# What does set -e do in this nginx initialization script?

Tags: shell

This is my code, I don't understand it completely. I would really appreciate your help

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

envsubst < /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an Nginx thing, it's a Unix shell thing, the [`set`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/set/) command. `set -e` means:

> When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns  an  exit
> status  value  >0,  and  is not part of the compound list following a while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR
> list, and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the shell shall immediately exit.

Comment: and what does the second line do?

Comment: @NoorulainIbrahim - According to a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=envsubst), it [loads environment variables](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/envsubst.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

it is flag for `sh` you can look at `man sh` its description

```
 -e errexit       If not interactive, exit immediately if any
                            untested command fails.  The exit status of a com‐
                            mand is considered to be explicitly tested if the
                            command is used to control an if, elif, while, or
                            until; or if the command is the left hand operand
                            of an “&&” or “||” operator.
```

Comment: and what does the second line do?

Comment: I think it compile default.conf from template and env variables